# fPrintf an integer

Tags: c, printf

I am new to C and I am surprised that there is not straight forward function to achieve what I want.

I am executing a program and need to write an integer value to a file. I have code snippet which helps me write into the file:

```
FILE *in_file  = fopen("test.txt", "w"); 
    fprintf(in_file,"Test");
    // all done!
    fclose(in_file);
```

This code is successfully able to write a string into a file. Now, when I try to write an integer value into that file it does not like it because I guess Fprintf likes to write only string into the files:

so the following code does not work:

```
int argc = 10;
FILE *in_file  = fopen("test.txt", "w"); 
    fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d",argc);
    // all done!
    fclose(in_file);
```

it throws following error:

> error: too few arguments to function ‘int printf(const char*, ...)’
>   printf( );

Now,  I tried to find how to print an integer to the file in C but did not find any straightfoward answers. So I am left with two options, either I try to find  a way to convert this integer to a string or have Fprintf write integer value to the file.

I am not sure which one is best option. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you claiming that the edited code `fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d",argc);` still gives you the error message?

Comment: That is what is heppening. I am able to print strings successfully.`int  something = 5;
 FILE *in_file  = fopen("test.txt", "w"); 
 fprintf(in_file,"%d",something);
    // all done!
 fclose(in_file);` This isn't working as well

Comment: You will need to show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your problem, and specify the compiler you are using. That is, show a small code example that if I fed it as is to the same compiler you are using, I would see the same error message. As it is now, I do not know what compiler you are using, nor am I able to get a similar error.

Comment: Your error message `error: too few arguments to function ‘int printf(const char*, ...)’` mentions function `printf()` - no leading `f`.  Your posted code does _not_ use function `printf()`, but function `fprintf()`.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. My code had a printF() below which had the error. So actually error was not with the posted code. I am really sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in this line `fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d,argc");` you should change it to `fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d" , argc);`

Comment: Actually I am sorry. It is the way you suggested already (in_file,"entry value: %d" , argc). I am really sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Minor mistake, the `argc` should be put outside of the string literal in all of the [*printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) methods.

```
fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d",argc);
```

> int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
>
> ... (additional arguments)
>
> Depending on the format string, the function may expect a sequence of additional arguments, each containing a value to be used to replace a format specifier in the format string (or a pointer to a storage location, for n).
>   There should be at least **as many of these arguments as the number of values specified in the format specifiers**. Additional arguments are ignored by the function.

Comment: Actually I am sorry. It is the way you suggested already (in_file,"entry value: %d" , argc). I am really sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fprintf(in_file,"entry value: %d", argc);
```

Comment: Actually I am sorry. It is the way you suggested already (in_file,"entry value: %d" , argc). I am really sorry for the confusion.